# Why are my Apple Push Notifications not sent to the app?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I have a weird issue.

I send push notifications to my iOS application, which are properly received by the iPhone. However, only once in a while is `didReceiveRemoteNotification` called (or `didReceiveRemoteNotification: fetchCompletionHandler`) according to the `NSLog` statements I have put in these callbacks.

I have tried being in the foreground, in the background, with the screen on or off, I can't figure out why the phone registers the notifications but the callbacks aren't responding reliably.

Comment: Could your push notifications be being rate limited? That is a possibility for silent push notifications. Have you tried changing device?

Comment: @RhythmicFistman I have the same issue with several iPhones running 8.1 and 8.2. Thanks for the pointer, I'll check it up.